# What to do when a particular user is giving low quality answer to his own question and accepting them?

Tags: discussion

While reading Q&A on SO, I found one user who is behaving strange so I checked his profile and found that he is asking questions and answering them, with answers that are not really helpful (both question and answers have low quality) and he is accepting those answers as the solution.

In some questions he asked for a suggestion and then argued with other users when that user asked "What have you tried?" ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757414/draw-curved-text-on-image-using-go/32905377#comment53355211_32757414)) and some time he just providing the links/plugin as an answer and accepting them, m afraid that this will lead to wrong way to current/future user as other user notify him about this([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355314/how-to-access-configuration-file-from-subfolder-in-go/32356198#comment52585785_32356198)) but still he accepted as answer. Then what to do in these type of condition and what to do with this type of user who is not serving to SO community but only increasing spam on site.(His Q&A are not useful at all).

**NOTE**: I tried to search on google and SE but did not find any question like this but still if i did any mistake while asking this question then please forgive me. And m not sure in which tag i should put this question so help me in this. Thanx

More examples of that user's behavior: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132722/filter-function-by-category-and-company-angular/34133003#34133003) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757414/draw-curved-text-on-image-using-go/32905377#32905377) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355314/how-to-access-configuration-file-from-subfolder-in-go/32356198#32356198) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960343/initialize-multiple-connection-pools-once-for-all-application-at-startup/31961332#31961332) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038957/angularjs-application-with-different-customizations/34061827#34061827)

Comment: Is this some kind of rant ?? certainly the user will get dvs is the questions are problematic, and he is not gaining reputation of this.

Comment: Some people just want a meta effect going on @g24l right thing to do is just to DV and flag, move along.

Comment: Note that voting on a bunch of a particular user's posts is considered serial voting and will get reversed. Don't target a particular user for voting.

Comment: Well there's no such thing as serial-flagging right? You can always just flag @BSMP And I meant "DV and Flag" as for a general rule of thumb, not just for this particular case

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton - Yes, but I wanted to warn the OP since it sounded like they might just run through this user's posts and vote on all of them all at once.

Comment: @BSMP, no m not running behind this user and giving downvote to all but just asking what to do. Sorry if i made any mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there are flags or closure reasons that apply to the answers / questions, then use them. You can also downvote, when the answers / questions are bad.

Basically, vote on them as you would any other post.
It's irrelevant **who** wrote the answer.

Comment: thanx for reply but they are old one and m afraid but few question m not familiar with them but can see other users are giving downvote means they are not useful at all, then what to do? isn't there any way to close them so they won't lead to wrong way to others?

Comment: Like I said: just vote on them. If the answer / question is bad, it will eventually be closed / deleted.

Comment: Sure but at present i did not see any bad answer which got deleted. still i can see a lot answer with 5 to 8 downvotes. but thanx for reply and now will clean the site with appropriate downvotes to make SO better :)

Comment: but I guess "meta effect" is far more attractive @Cerbrus

Comment: @Leothelion: "i did not see any bad answer which got deleted" -- that would be the idea, yes?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, m just saying that i have seen answer with 8 to 10 downvote but they still exist that's why i said that line.